Is there any intuitive way to understand the Strong and Weak Equivalence Principle?
The WEP talks about the indistinguishability of motion in a constant gravitational field and an inertial force in an accelerating reference frame. The SEP further claims that this indistinguishability is not limited to mechanics experiments but also, for example, optical or electromagnetic ones. This is a bold claim- and not so intuitive! What makes gravity so special? Could this be the case for electromagnetism too, given how strikingly similar classical gravity and electromagnetism are? 
Having studied special relativity, I am not new to Einstein's genius(or postulates), but I am sure he had his reasons to propose them(before working on GR entirely!). Maybe this is more philosophical but I am looking for an explanation 'less out of the blue' or a classical analogy. Any insightful opinions would be great too. Thanks!

I just came across this essay Equivalence Principle in Classical and Quantum Gravity. I think it addresses your question.
